# Lost my column headings SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I had the following dummy code (you can use this to test):

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
  ProductID VARCHAR (50),
  Period    VARCHAR (6),
  Value     DECIMAL (15, 2)
);
INSERT dbo.Products VALUES
('North', '201201', 100),
('South', '201202', 500);

SELECT ProductID, Period, Value
FROM dbo.Products AS p;

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Period)
  FROM (SELECT p.Period FROM dbo.Products AS p
  GROUP BY p.Period) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT ProductID, Period, Value
   FROM dbo.Products AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value) FOR Period IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE dbo.Products
```

It generated output but contained NULLs - the column headings were present though.

To remove the NULLs, my code now looks like this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.products
(
  ProductID VARCHAR (50),
  Period    VARCHAR (6),
  Value     DECIMAL (15, 2)
);
INSERT dbo.products VALUES
('North', '201201', 100),
('South', '201202', 500);

SELECT ProductID, Period, Value
FROM dbo.products AS p;

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @selectList NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Period)
  FROM (SELECT p.Period FROM dbo.products AS p
  GROUP BY p.Period) AS x;

SET @selectList = N'';
SELECT @selectList += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Period) + ', 0)' 
  FROM (SELECT p.Period FROM dbo.products AS p
  GROUP BY p.Period) AS x;
PRINT '@selectList = ' + @selectList
SET @selectList = STUFF(@selectlist, 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'
SELECT ProductId, ' + @selectList + ' 
  FROM
(
  SELECT ProductID, Period, Value
   FROM dbo.products AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value) FOR Period IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';

PRINT '@sql = ' + @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

But now my column headings show [No column name]?

How do I get the headings back?

Comment: The two scripts are included in the post.

Comment: @TimRichards . . . SQL Fiddle has the column names in both cases (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d898d/3).  Something else changed.

Comment: I was able to replicate Tim's issue using Management Studio ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Comment: Thanks Chris for your no-nonsense, straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon! When setting your @selectList variable be sure to specify the Alias for the column names with "AS" ...

```
SET @selectList = N'';
SELECT @selectList += N', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Period) + ', 0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Period)
  FROM (SELECT p.Period FROM dbo.products AS p
  GROUP BY p.Period) AS x;
PRINT '@selectList = ' + @selectList
SET @selectList = STUFF(@selectlist, 1, 1, '');
```

Comment: Outstanding Sir, many thanks.  I was told that dealing with developers would be like wading through treacle but you have proven that well-founded assertion totally wrong.